# Encrypting files with a decryption key

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl

I'm writing a program that needs to encrypt a log file using `openssl` and have a decryption key. For example I want to encrypt this file:

> This is a test of encrypting a file
>
> This is a test of encrypting a file

Using `openssl` and I want to be able to decrypt it when I put in some decryption key, for sake of argument `123456789` will be the key.

```
def decrypt
  print 'Enter key: '
  key = gets.chomp
  if key == decryption_key
    # decrypt file
  else
    # don't decrypt file
  end
end
```

I've read the docs on `openssl` but I still don't fully understand how it works, could someone give me an example of what I'm trying to do, along with an example of the decryption part please?

Comment: did you read these docs? http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html

Comment: @Kris I did, it's just not in terms that I can understand at this point. I think what I need is an example.

Comment: OpenSSL needs a pair of keys. The keys are **NOT** passwords, and they are far stronger than passwords. The private key can be protected by a passphrase (something like a password).

Comment: It sounds like you want something like this: https://github.com/chicks/aes or if you want to do it yourself this: https://gist.github.com/byu/99651

Comment: @Kris Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [aes](https://github.com/chicks/aes) gem you can do something like:

```
key = AES.key    
b64 = AES.encrypt("A super secret message", key)
AES.decrypt(b64, key) # => "A super secret message"
```